# Why two different coils for one output in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, schematics

It's a backlight circuit for an iPhone 6s. Previous models only used one coil, one diode for one output.

This model uses 2 coils and 2 diodes. Coils are different values. Can't find datasheet for the ic so I'm curious why two would be used.

Is it for providing smooth current output?[image]

Comment: In the circuit U4020 which is the line that switches it on?

Answer (score 2):

One of the things I can imagine is that the different coils are for different operating conditions - one might be more efficient at lower power and higher frequency switching, the other might be for high brightness.
Ofcourse, without the datasheet of the component this is just a wild guess.

Comment: Yeah I've been guessing myself. So with your guess about two operating conditions, do you mean when software demands brighter screen or? Can't see when there'd be two different operating conditions just for backlight

Comment: @ohmmy Indeed, I was thinking in terms of brightness - high brightness requires a lot more power. I am by no means an expert on this topic, however.

Comment: Ditto.  Probably brightness.  With two digital switches that gives 4 states; you have 4 brightness levels from dark to full on.